# Preprocessor initialize array

Tags: c++, boost, preprocessor

How, if necessary, using boost preprocessor, initialize the array as follows:

```
INIT_ARRAY(plus,minus)
//extract to 
std::array<std::pair<char const *,std::string>, 2> array{{
{"plus", std::string("plus")}, {"minus", std::string("minus")} }};

INIT_ARRAY(plus,minus,multiply)
//extract to 
std::array<std::pair<char const *,std::string>, 3> array{{
{"plus", std::string("plus")}, {"minus", std::string("minus")}, {"multiply", std::string("multiply")} }};
```

P.S. Couldn't solve the problem with the last comma in the initializer `(...{n-1} , {n} ,)`
and counting the number of arguments to pass to `std::array<...,n>`. I use the preprocessor, since the names passed to the macro will be used later for code generation. Used c++20

Comment: If you're using C++17 or later, you can just let `std::array` deduce its arguments from the initializer, no counting required. If not, please tag the appropriate C++ version.

Comment: @Quentin I would like to see the full declaration of the macro that implements the initializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/comma_if.html) for conditional commas, and [`BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/variadic_size.html) to work out the size beforehand.

This should work (for non-empty arrays):

```cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/size.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>


#define INIT_ARRAY_INITIALIZER(r, _, i, e) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i) {BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(e), std::string(BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(e))}

#define INIT_ARRAY(...) \
std::array<std::pair<char const *, std::string>, \
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)> array{{ \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(INIT_ARRAY_INITIALIZER, _, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) \
}};
```

Comment: Can you recommend preprocessor tutorials?
Thanks for the answer. Working.